# Saving workspaces

Tags: workspace

Is it possible to save workspaces?
For instance terminal on first, vscode on second, browser on third...
On power up, I would like to be able to find it the same way it was when powering down

Comment: This isn't possible in vanilla elementary OS, but it sounds like a great idea for a productivity app.